# Exactly what is the best way to fix this code such that it won't generate a syntax error?

Tags: python, for-loop, dictionary, syntax-error, python-3.4

I can't seem to find quite what's wrong with this (not so little) for statement that would cause a syntax error. Just to be clear, this is coded in Python 3.4. If you'd like to take a look at some of the preceeding code, I'll happily provide some, but its not causing any issue as far as I'm aware. Here's the for statement; that last line is so that I can be sure everything makes sense in the end.

EDIT: Code is now properly indented (sorry about that). Each "(dict(item))" statement is meant to reference the dictionary created on line 3 (which will vary in title depending upon which item in playerList is being adressed). Is there a way to call the name of that dictionary without actually knowing it (evidently my way doesn't work at all)? You'll have to excuse me if I've done something simply outright strange, as I'm rather new to Python, not to mention coding in general.

EDIT 2: Changed question title from "Exactly what here is causing a syntax error?"

```
for item in playerList:
    playerList.index(item) = magicCharacterGenerationIndex
    dict(item) = {
        'Name' : "",
        'Class' : "",
        'Skills' : {},
        'Inventory' : [],
        'Magic' : 0,
        'Luck' : 0,
        'Gender' : ""
        }
    (dict(item))['Name'] = playerNames[magicCharacterGenerationIndex]
    (dict(item))['Class'] = playerClasses[magicCharacterGenerationIndex]
    (dict(item))['Gender'] = playerGenders[magicCharacterGenerationIndex]
    (dict(item))['Luck'] = random.randint(2,12)
    # This bit populates character skills.
    if (dict(item))['Class'] == Knight:
        (dict(item))['Skills'] = {
            'Appraise': 1,
            'Brawl': 2,
            'Melee': 3,
            'Negotiate': 4,
            'Ranged': 3,
            'Sneak': 1,
            'Status': 4,
            'Track': 2,
            }
    elif (dict(item))['Class'] == Barbarian:
        (dict(item))['Skills'] = {
            'Appraise': 2,
            'Brawl': 4,
            'Melee': 4,
            'Negotiate': 1,
            'Ranged': 1,
            'Sneak': 3,
            'Status': 2,
            'Track': 3,
            }
    elif (dict(item))['Class'] == Thief:
        (dict(item))['Skills'] = {
            'Appraise': 4,
            'Brawl': 2,
            'Melee': 3,
            'Negotiate': 1,
            'Ranged': 2,
            'Sneak': 4,
            'Status': 1,
            'Track': 3,
            }
    elif (dict(item))['Class'] == Ranger:
        (dict(item))['Skills'] = {
            'Appraise': 1,
            'Brawl': 2,
            'Melee': 3,
            'Negotiate': 1,
            'Ranged': 4,
            'Sneak': 3,
            'Status': 2,
            'Track': 4,
            }
    elif (dict(item))['Class'] == Enchanter:
        (dict(item))['Skills'] = {
            'Appraise': 3,
            'Brawl': 1,
            'Melee': 1,
            'Negotiate': 4,
            'Ranged': 2,
            'Sneak': 3,
            'Status': 4,
            'Track': 2,
            }
    # This next bit populates character inventories.
    if (dict(item))['Class'] == Knight:
        (dict(item))['Inventory'] = ['Kite Shield','Broadsword','Noble Steed','Lance']
    elif (dict(item))['Class'] == Barbarian:
        (dict(item))['Inventory'] = ['Dane Axe','Large Chunk of Beef','Spear','Magic Helmet']
    elif (dict(item))['Class'] == Thief:
        (dict(item))['Inventory'] = ['Dagger','Stolen Coinpurse','Lockpicks and Tools','Throwing Knives (8 Knives)']
    elif (dict(item))['Class'] == Ranger:
        (dict(item))['Inventory'] = ['Bow','Flint and Steel','Saxe Knife','Sturdy Arrows (36 Arrows)']
    elif (dict(item))['Class'] == Enchanter:
        (dict(item))['Skills'] = ['Sling','Spellbook','Raven Familiar','Staff of Magic Missiles (4 Charges)']
    # This segment eliminates the magic stat for all non-enchanter characters, and gives all enchanters a random Magic stat above 50.
    if (dict(item))['Class'] == Enchanter:
        (dict(item))['Magic'] = 50 + random.randint(0,50)
    else:
        del (dict(item))['Magic']
    print(dict(item))
```

Comment: Your code isn't indented correctly. The second line should be indented from the first line. If this is just a paste-to-stackoverflow problem, then please fix it so your code in the question looks the same as your source code.

Comment: Also, you can't assign something to the result of a function call (`dict(item) = ...`). What are you actually trying to do there?

Comment: That looks like a cast statement in other languages, but it's not valid in Python.

Comment: "Is there a way to call the name of that dictionary without actually knowing it (evidently my way doesn't work at all)?" Do you really need to know that name? Won't it work just fine if you just create some dictionary?

Comment: I do need to know all the dictionary names, as the up to five seperate dictionaries will be created, and I'll be using those dictionaries to reference information throughout the rest of the code.

Comment: Surely you can cut that down to a smaller example. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, and/or http://sscce.org/

Comment: @CharlesDuffy You'll have to excuse me, I'm new. Will do in future.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you want a dictionary of dictionaries, so you should create an empty dictionary outside your loop:

```
mydict = {}
```

Then, you need to replace every single `(dict(item))` with `mydict[item]`.  The very first one where you say `dict(item) = {...` is causing you the syntax error, because you are putting the result of a call on the LHS of an assignment.

The inner parentheses are for call-syntax, so you need to change them out to brackets for indexing syntax.  And as others have implied in the comments, you don't need the outer parentheses anyway.

And you don't want to keep calling dict() -- that creates a new one every time.

And finally, after you get that going, you might realize that you want a class instead of a dictionary.  The attribute syntax is much nicer than all the parentheses and quoting.

Comment: Alright, that cleared things up quite nicely. Thanks for that. I've changed my methods a touch for different reasons, but you fix was still relevant to making my code work, anyway.